# How to create column name with space?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anybody tell me how to create columns with space like "FULL NAMES"?
I've tried like the following but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE info
(
Full Names varchar(20),
Physical Address varchar(20),
Moviesrented varchar(100),
Salutation varchar(20),
Category varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (address)
)
```

Comment: Backticks or double quotes (if ANSI quotes are enabled).  But it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: Even if you *can* do it, it's better to not do it.

Comment: Why is it not 'Movies Rented'?  Consistency is good!  Actually, it would be better to use 'FullNames' and 'PhysicalAddress'.  Note that if you use backticks (MySQL only) or double quotes (around a delimited identifier using Standard SQL), the name becomes case-sensitive, and you'll need to use backticks or double quotes every time you need to refer to the column by name.

Comment: Also, this is a terrible design for a table.  For one thing, you can't have more than one person living at a given address (primary keys must be unique) - which would be a problem in some housing situations.  The information is also somewhat unrelated to each other, and some may be better placed in their own tables.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It appears [MySQL doesn't respect the standard with regard to case-sensitivity of quoted identifiers](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/42040). But I do agree with all the other things you've said in your comment.

Comment: @AndriyM: Interesting — you can tell I don't use MySQL...I just know some of its quirks by reputation.

Answer (score 8):

Just put the name in backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE info (`Full Names` varchar(20), ...)
```

But that's no good handle for naming your columns.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why you want that. But to answer your question, wrap it with backticks.

```
`Full Names` VARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: I kinda understand why one would want spaces in column names...it ends up prettier when you're browsing the tables in myadmin and such.  But it still can cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: @cHao I totally agree with you.