# dynamically create mysql columns in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a private api that unifies our many dbs/vendor data in one sql db.

We face a challenge with our ESP where our marketers are always changing/adding new columns.  We want this app to scale with those column changes and not require massaging columns every time they change names or add new attributes.

I need to create a list of columns on the fly using Rails (we don't want to do this 100% in Mysql, because we're renaming some columns  in mapping).

```
table = "customer"
attrs = ["vendor_cm_name_d", "vendor_cm_email address_d", "vendor_cm_date added_d", "vendor_cm_extid_d" ]

attrs.each_with_index do |attr, i|
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  connection.execute( "ALTER TABLE #{table}  ADD COLUMN #{attr} VARCHAR(15);"  )
  # this didnt work :-( connection.close 
end
```

This approach works a single column but fails with more than one element in the array. reading the logs (pasted below) seems like it's trying to run the entire statement as one call,  not transactionally.  I tried adding in a connection.close before the end of each loop and that didn't work either.  All pointers are welcome.

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'address_d VARCHAR(15)' at line 1: ALTER TABLE customer  ADD COLUMN vendor_cm_email address_d VARCHAR(15);
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'address_d VARCHAR(15)' at line 1: ALTER TABLE customer  ADD COLUMN vendor_cm_email address_d VARCHAR(15);
```

Comment: This is probably a super bad idea. Why not pivot to a schemaless type design? MySQL 5.7 supports JSON columns which are great for this sort of thing, though the down-side is they can't be easily indexed or manipulated. Postgres provides excellent support for JSON, you can index it and manipulate it quite easily, which might be worth considering as an option. There's also more pure document stores like MongoDB that go all-in on this concept.

Comment: Another more pure RDBMS approach is to create a key/value table pair for your row data. This can get extremely messy and is often held up as an anti-pattern, but it can get you out of a jam like this where you really don't know what data you need to accommodate. Altering large tables can bring your server to its knees and can cause severe service disruptions at scale. It's something you want to do reluctantly, not by design.

Comment: @tadman yeah I agree. I;d never do this anywhere else but a private api for our data warehouse.

Comment: If you're doing it specifically for warehousing, the [Star Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) can simplify implementation.

Comment: Sorry that submitted early @tadman.  Upgrading sql version or  using serialized columns is deal breaker.  We have too much investment in SQL that;s not worth getting into here, and we need to be able to query by sql on a col by col basis. Fully understand your points/approach tho, appreciate the  notes so far!

Comment: I think you can flip to a star-schema style approach which minimizes the impact of these schema changes. A pure key-value method is a lot more clunky, way more rows to manage, but it can work in a pinch if your data is fairly uniform in nature, like all numerical.

Comment: Looks like the problem is from space in the column name, you can add `` if you really want space. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009440/how-to-create-column-name-with-space

Answer (score 2):

Your `sql` doesn't work because column names have space. Wrap you column names in generated `sql` with quotes.

```
attrs.each_with_index do |x, i|
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  connection.execute "ALTER TABLE #{table}  ADD COLUMN \"#{x}\" VARCHAR(15);" 
# this didnt work :-( connection.close 
end
```

Though I would rather not go down the path of writing sql myself. Instead you can create a service like this:

```
class DbService < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def initialize(table_name)
    @table_name = table_name
  end
  def add_string_column(column_name)
    add_column @table_name, column_name, :string
  end
end
```

And then do something like

```
service = DbService.new("customer")
attrs.each do |column_name|
  service.add_string_column(column_name)
end
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that.  I used a rails helper to replace spaces with underscores, that clearly had an issue. Resolved.  Thanks so much!!